# Method to search for specific character strings

Tags: python

I have two different kinds of URLs in a list:

The first kind looks like this and starts with the word 'meldung':

```
meldung/xxxxx.html
```

The other kind starts with 'artikel':

```
artikel/xxxxx.html
```

I want to detect if a URL starts with 'meldung' or 'artikel' and then do different operations based on that. To achieve this I tired to use a loop with if and else conditions:

```
for line in r:
    if re.match(r'^meldung/', line):
        print('je')
    else:
        print('ne')
```

I also tried this with line.startswith():

```
for line in r:
    if line.startswith('meldung/'):
        print('je')
    else:
        print('ne')
```

But both methods dont work since the strings I am checking dont have any whitespaces.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Why not ```r.startswith()```?

Comment: @Antimon tried this too but doesnt work. Added it to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following, if the links are stored as strings within the list:

```
for line in r:
    if ‘meldung’ in line:
        print(‘je’)
    else:
        print(‘ne’)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
r = ['http://example.com/meldung/page1.html', 'http://example.com/artikel/page2.html']

for line in r:
    url_tokens = line.split('/')
    if url_tokens[-2] == 'meldung':
        print(url_tokens[-1])  # the xxxxx.html part
    elif url_tokens[-2] == 'artikel':
        print('ne')
    else:
        print('something else')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using regex:

```
import re

def check(string):
    if (re.search('^meldung|artikel*', string)):
        print("je")
    else:
        print("ne")

for line in r:
    check(line)
```